# Strings vs Symbols when using HashWithIndifferentAccess?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am learning in Ruby on Rails 4.0 that Rails has the ability to reference a hash's values, via a key that can either be a symbol or string, using the class `HashWithIndifferentAccess`. For example, the `params` hash can be referenced through both a symbol or a string, because it uses the class `HashWithIndifferentAccess`.

i.e.: `params["id"] and params[:id] --> both access the id in the params hash`

Although both can be used and are acceptable by Rails, is there clearly one preferred over other, either for best practice/performance reasons? My initial thought was that it would be better to use symbols due to the fact that once they are stored, they retain that piece of memory. This is contrasted against strings, which a new piece of memory is needed for every string.

Is this correct? Or does it truly not matter whether strings or symbols are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby Strings are mutable, which can bring some unpredictability and reduced performance. For these reasons Ruby also offers the choice of Symbols. The big difference would be that Symbols are immutable. While mutable object can be changed the immutable ones can only be overwritten. Symbols play more nicely with the memory and thus gain on performance, but if not careful enough the memory footprint of your app will increase.

Using Strings or Symbols comes down to understanding both of the terms and how they will serve the purpose in benefit of the overall app health and performance. This is the reason why maybe there is no strict definition of where to use String and where Symbol.

What I would maybe give as a guidance of what is recommended where:

- Symbol - internal identifiers, variables not meant to change
- String - variables that are changing or printed out

`HashWithIndifferentAccess` ends up mapping internally all the symbols to strings.

```
h = ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(test: 'test')
```

If you try to retrieve the keys of the created hash (h) you will get the keys as strings

```
h.keys # => ["test"]
```

Comment: If you say `HashWithIndifferentAccess` ends up mapping all symbols to strings, should it not matter then?

Comment: If we go into details lets say that if using strings with `HashWithIndifferentAccess` would perform a little bit better just because you will avoid the casting from Symbol to String.

Answer (score 0):

A couple highlights:

First, as of Ruby 2.3, string immutability (objects with same content point to same place in memory) is an option. From what I understand, this functionality is going to become the default in Ruby 3.0. Here's an example:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

a = 'foo'
b = 'foo'

puts a.object_id
puts b.object_id

puts a.equal?(b)
```

Run the file:

```
➜  ruby test.rb  
70186103229600  
70186103229600  
true
```

Second, symbols are *generally* preferred as hash keys (see [this popular style](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#symbols-as-keys) guide).

If you're interested in learning more about how `HashWithIndifferentAccess` works, [here's a good blog post](http://codefol.io/posts/Deep-Rails-Understanding-HashWithIndifferentAccess-Understanding-the-Params-Hash). The short version is that all keys are converted to strings behind the scenes.

Comment: I definitely understand that symbols are preferred as hash keys in pure Ruby. My question has to do with the Rails class `HashWithIndifferentAccess`. Just curious how Rails handles both symbols and strings, and whether one is preferred vs the other.

Comment: Not following you. You wrote "I understand that symbols are preferred" and then "Just curious whether one is preferred."

Comment: Also, I've added a bit at the end about how `HasWithIndifferentAccess` works.